# how to make smileys emoji in html and css only

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me with building this smiles?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope you might get some idea how to design emojis.

```css
[class^="emoji"]{
  width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #9E9E9E;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
  position:relative;
}
.emoji1:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
.emoji1:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
.emoji1 i:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #000;
    bottom: 14px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 2px;
}





.emoji2:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 7px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 13px;
    transform: rotate(20deg);

}
.emoji2:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 7px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 13px;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
.emoji2 i:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #000;
    bottom: 14px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

span{
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="emoji1"><i></i></span>

<span class="emoji2"><i></i></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your own images and add CSS such as this:

```
a {
  background-image : url('url_of_my_image.jpg');
}
a:hover {
  background-image : url('url_of_my_image_at_hover.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the image or get the link of the image and try using this link where ever you want to.